# I want to print the value from csv file dynamically

Tags: shell-script, csv

I want to print the values from properties file dynamically I am using below code but getting wrong output.

#### testProperty.properties

```
edmcws,edmbws,edmwt
```

#### Code

```
file=/ThreadDump/testProperty.properties

count=$(head -1 $file | sed 's/[^,]//g' | wc -c)
echo "$count"

for((i=1;i<=$count;i++))
do
abc=$(awk -F "," '(NR==1){print $($i)}' $file)

echo "$abc"
done
```

#### Output

```
3
edmcws,edmbws,edmwt
edmcws,edmbws,edmwt
edmcws,edmbws,edmwt
```

But when I hard-code the value I am getting  correct output.

#### Code

```
file=/ThreadDump/testProperty.properties

count=$(head -1 $file | sed 's/[^,]//g' | wc -c)
echo "$count"

for((i=1;i<=$count;i++))
do
abc=$(awk -F "," '(NR==1){print $1}' $file)

echo "$abc"
done
```

#### Output

```
3
edmcws
edmcws
edmcws
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `abc=$(awk -F "," '(NR==1){print $($i)}' $file)`. Here you use single quotes around your awk skript. Therefore variables like `$i` are not replaced by their value.

If `i=1`, `awk` will therefore literally see `$($i)` instead of `$1` as given in the second example.

You can give variables to awk using the `-v` option.

Maybe `awk` is not the perfect tool for the job. I would probably simply use

```
perl -wnle 'print for split ","'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the awk body is in single quotes, awk does not see the shell variable. awk thinks you mean an awk variable `i`. That variable is undefined, so in a numeric context it has the value zero. Thus `$i` is interpreted by awk as `$0`, or the whole line.

You need to pass the shell variable into awk.

```
for ((i=1; i<=$count; i++))
do
    abc=$(awk -F "," -v col=$i 'NR==1 {print $col}' $file)
    #................^^^^^^^^^...............^^^^
    echo "$abc"
done
```

However, there's a better way than calling awk 3 separate times:

```
while IFS=, read -ra fields; do
    printf "%s\n" "${fields[@]}"
    # or do stuff with the individual fields
    for ((i=0; i < ${#fields[@]}; i++)); do
        echo "${fields[i]}"
    done
done < "$file"
```

- the `while` loop, with the file's contents redirected into it, loop over the lines of the file
- `IFS=,` instructs the `read` command to do word splitting on commas
- `read -r` means to not interpret any special characters as anything but regular chars.
- `read -a fields` reads the words in the line into an array variable named `fields`